# How to get a single value from a json response using PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, extract

I have the following json. I would like to extract only the value 41 from "id": "41" from the response below. Assuming I don't know what that value is, how can I extract that single value, assign it to a variable and see the output?

```
{
  "page": {
    "offset": 0,
    "total": 36,
    "totalFilter": 1
  },
  "list": [
    {
      "id": "41",
      "type": "ATBR",
      "hostName": "AAMS",
      "userId": "",
      "userName": "",
      "status": "CONNECTED",
      "poolName": "",
      "fullyQualifiedHostName": "-",
      "updatedBy": "mscr",
      "updatedOn": "2020-06-24T23:28:11.239894Z",
      "botAgentVersion": "9.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

so far I have the below, but I can't figure out how to only get single value

```
$json = @"
{
  "page": {
    "offset": 0,
    "total": 36,
    "totalFilter": 1
  },
  "list": [
    {
      "id": "41",
      "type": "ATBR",
      "hostName": "AAMS",
      "userId": "",
      "userName": "",
      "status": "CONNECTED",
      "poolName": "",
      "fullyQualifiedHostName": "-",
      "updatedBy": "mscr",
      "updatedOn": "2020-06-24T23:28:11.239894Z",
      "botAgentVersion": "9.0"
    }
  ]
}
"@

$x = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

$x.list[0]
$id = $x.list | Where { $_.list -eq "id" }
```

and my current output result is below. I would only like to extract 41 from it.

```
id                     : 41
type                   : ATBR
hostName               : AAMS
userId                 : 
userName               : 
status                 : CONNECTED
poolName               : 
fullyQualifiedHostName : -
updatedBy              : mscr
updatedOn              : 2020-06-24T23:28:11.239894Z
botAgentVersion        : 9.0
```

any help is greatly appreciated - thanks in advance

Comment: `$id = ($x.list | where id).id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have converted your JSON into an object, you can use `Where-Object` or `Where` to filter the `list` array element that contains `id` with a non-empty and non-null value. Then use the member access operator `.` to retrieve the value of the `id` property.

```
$json = @"
{
  "page": {
    "offset": 0,
    "total": 36,
    "totalFilter": 1
  },
  "list": [
    {
      "id": "41",
      "type": "ATBR",
      "hostName": "AAMS",
      "userId": "",
      "userName": "",
      "status": "CONNECTED",
      "poolName": "",
      "fullyQualifiedHostName": "-",
      "updatedBy": "mscr",
      "updatedOn": "2020-06-24T23:28:11.239894Z",
      "botAgentVersion": "9.0"
    }
  ]
}
"@

$x = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$id = ($x.list | Where id).id
```

Using `Where id` basically checks if `[boo]$x.list.id` returns `true`. So if you were to use `Where userId`, it would return nothing since `[bool]$x.list.userId` evaluates to `false`.

---

You can alternatively retrieve the `id` value using `Select-Object`:

```
$id = $x.list | Where id | Select-Object -Expand id
```

---

Note that if you have more than one object in `list` (since it is an array) that contains `id` with a value, multiple `id` values will be returned.